# All Bitmaps were eliminated from app but they're still listed in Memory Analyzer. How do I get rid of them?

Tags: android, bitmap, uri, out-of-memory

Even after eliminating all the Bitmaps in my app, they are still appearing in the memory analyzer. (see screen capture below)  Please can you help me understand why they are still listed and help me to finally remove them?  I'm certain there are no bitmaps since I also removed the Bitmap import.
[image]

In place of creating bitmaps, I now create the images from Uri's as shown in the code below. Does this approach generate bitmaps?

```
try {
    InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageURI);
    imageDrawable = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, imageURI.toString() );
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    imageDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.default_image);
}
```

FYI, the reason I eliminated the bitmaps is because they appeared to be causing out of memory crashes.  Even after carefully following the SO guidance on how to reduce bitmap size (inSampleSize, bitmap.recycle(), etc.) the app would crash with OOM every other time it was launched.  I got annoyed and decided to eliminate bitmaps.  But, like kids that won't move out, they still appear to be dogging me.

Comment: What is the Size of each image? http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html

Comment: **"Does this approach generate bitmaps?"** - To quote the docs for `Drawable`... "Though usually not visible to the application, Drawables may take a variety of forms: Bitmap: the simplest Drawable, a PNG or JPEG image." See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html

Comment: @Squonk: That is enlightening and frustrating all in the same breath.  So I'm back to square one with bitmaps chewing up memory.  I've subsequently tried to use `imageDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 60, 60)` hoping that would reduce the memory footprint.  Unfortunately that had no effect--the MAT report is unchanged from that shown above. Is there any way to control the size of these Bitmaps masquerading as Drawables?  FYI, the largest image is 100x97 so they're not exactly large.

Answer (score 0):

> Though usually not visible to the application, Drawables may take a
> variety of forms:
>
> Bitmap: the simplest Drawable, a PNG or JPEG image.
>
> Nine Patch: an extension to the PNG format allows it to specify
> information about how to stretch it and place things inside of it.
>
> Shape: contains simple drawing commands instead of a raw bitmap,
> allowing it to resize better in some cases.
>
> Layers: a compound drawable, which draws multiple underlying drawables on top of each
> other. States: a compound drawable that selects one of a set of
> drawables based on its state.
>
> Levels: a compound drawable that selects
> one of a set of drawables based on its level.
>
> Scale: a compound drawable with a single child drawable, whose overall size is modified
> based on the current level.

That's from the Drawable description. So I believe that inside Drawable is just creating bitmaps for you

Comment: thanks for the answer but Squonk already pointed this out and it doesn't help me to solve the out of memory problem.  I've since isolated the out of memory error to a ListView's getView method.  I lost patience and decided to eliminate the images altogether.  Although that isn't an intellectually satisfying solution it has solved the OOM problem which has enabled me to move on.